# Why is the GZIP "os" header hard-coded to FAT in Java?

Tags: java, gzip

[RFC 1952](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1952) section 2.3.1 specifies that GZIP headers must contain an `OS` flag:

> **`OS` (Operating System)**. This identifies the type of file system on which compression took place.  This may be useful in determining end-of-line convention for text files. The currently defined values are as follows:

```
  0 - FAT filesystem (MS-DOS, OS/2, NT/Win32)
  1 - Amiga
  2 - VMS (or OpenVMS)
  3 - Unix
  4 - VM/CMS
  5 - Atari TOS
  6 - HPFS filesystem (OS/2, NT)
  7 - Macintosh
  8 - Z-System
  9 - CP/M
 10 - TOPS-20
 11 - NTFS filesystem (NT)
 12 - QDOS
 13 - Acorn RISCOS
255 - unknown
```

However, Java's GZIP serialisation instead writes a zero in all cases, as can be seen on [line 193 of GzipOutputStream.java](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream.java#L193). I've run tests on four different operating systems to confirm no other code is modifying this header after writing.

Why is this value hard-coded?

Comment: Questions about the original motivation of some design are always difficult to answer. We might speculate that the field value is not actually very helpful in practice, and that gzipped text files may have been produced by a different platform than the one gzipping it. Furthermore, the application g(un)zipping a file is not always the same one reading it, and passing the flag on to the caller when gunzipping is not part of the API.

Comment: I will point you to section 2.3.1.2 which says (in part) *A compliant compressor must produce files with correct ID1,
         ID2, CM, CRC32, and ISIZE, but may set all the other fields in
         the fixed-length part of the header to default values (255 for
         OS, 0 for all others).  The compressor must set all reserved
         bits to zero.*

Comment: @ElliottFrisch good point! but wouldn't this mean the code should be setting the OS flag to 255 instead of 0?

Comment: @KonradRudolph agreed - the field does not seem useful in today's day and age. I was merely curious in case someone knew the thought process behind this - it seems it's not a required flag as Elliott pointed out, but even then its default value seems wrong. There are also no bug reports about this, so I figured it is pretty much accepted behaviour to ignore these headers.

Comment: That's how I read it too, I'm guessing they picked `0` for compatibility reasons. Obviously `0` works. But I think you've found a bug. Well done.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I've submitted a bug report and it's been accepted [here](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8244706). Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Elliott pointed out, setting it to a default value is fine as per section 2.3.1.2 of the same RFC you reference:

> A compliant compressor must produce files with correct ID1, ID2, CM, CRC32, and ISIZE, but may set all the other fields in the fixed-length part of the header to default values (255 for OS, 0 for all others). The compressor must set all reserved bits to zero.

However, the default value is still incorrect, according to this very fragment - the default for the `OS` flag is 255, not 0. This was a **known bug** in the JDK as per [JDK-8244706](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8244706). It was fixed in Java version 16, early access build 16.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that a compliant compressor is not required to produce the correct OS field. The value of `255` for OS is in a sentence that begins "but may" - so the current implementation is still *compliant*.