# Gzip compression of a string gives different results in java11 vs java17

Tags: java, scala, gzip, java-17

I applied gzip compression to the string `test-string`. When I use Scala 2.13.8 with **Java 11.0.13** (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM), it results in the compressed string `H4sIAAAAAAAAACtJLS7RLS4pysxLBwCFdJByCwAAAA==.`

However, when I perform the same compression operation with Scala 2.13.8 on **Java 17.0.4.1** (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM), it yields `H4sIAAAAAAAA/ytJLS7RLS4pysxLBwCFdJByCwAAAA==.` however, both of these compressed strings correctly decompressed to retrieve the original string `test-string`.

I assume this can depend on several factors like Default Compression Levels: the default compression level might differ between Java 11 and Java 17, resulting in different output for the same input.
Algorithm Improvements: The Gzip implementation in Java 17 may have been optimized, leading to different compression results.Internal Implementation Details: The internal implementation details of Gzip compression may have changed between Java 11 and Java 17, affecting the compressed output.

What could be the reason behind this? I am attaching the code below.

```
val bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream("test-string".length)
val b64os = new Base64OutputStream(bos)
val gzip = new GZIPOutputStream(b64os)
gzip.write("test-string".getBytes("UTF-8"))
gzip.close()
val compressed = new String(bos.toByteArray, "UTF-8")
bos.close()
compressed.trim
```

Comment: Similar: [*Change in GZIPOutputStream behavior in Java 17?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77305259/642706)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If we look at both your outputs in hex, we have these two pieces of data

```
1f8b08000000000000ff2b492d2ed12d2e29cacc4b0700857490720b000000
                  ^^
1f8b08000000000000002b492d2ed12d2e29cacc4b0700857490720b000000
                  ^^
```

Basically 1 byte changed from 0 to 255 (ff in hex). That's the [OS header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61715912/why-is-the-gzip-os-header-hard-coded-to-fat-in-java) of the gzip format, which was changed from 0 to 255 in java 16 according to this :https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8244706